# Get difference between two dates and show nothing if date 1 is older

Tags: php, date

I want to get the days of difference between two dates and if date1 is older than date2, the missing days are not shown.

Right now with my code this happens:

```
    date1: 21/11/2020
    date2: 30/11/2020
    8 days difference -> OK

    date1: 21/11/2020
    date2: 01/11/2020
    20 days difference -> NO, FALSE, ERROR! show nothing!
```

Code:

```
$currentdate= new DateTime();  

$query = "SELECT * FROM premiun";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if ($namefound== $row["name"]) {

        $enddate= $row["enddate"];
        $dt = new DateTime($enddate);
        $diff = $dt->diff($currentdate);
```

Comment: No thing is happening, because code misses a closing '}'.  Please put more time in explaining your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `$diff->invert` if it is older or newer.

> Is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php